# Trying to see DOM in Chrome. Receiving SuperSocket could not be found error

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013, supersocket.net

I have a VisualStudio C# WindowFormApplication. I have been trying to get the DOM of a Chrome tab.  I came across a post on this site from earlier: 
[Accessing the DOM of a Chrome Tab from Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043136/accessing-the-dom-of-a-chrome-tab-from-visual-studio)

https://github.com/kerryjiang/SuperWebSocket/blob/master/Samples/BasicConsole/Program.cs

It detailed how to accomplish this. I rolled it into my program and I get a "SuperSocket" could not be found an error. There must be a reference I'm missing here, but I can't determine what it is.

```
using System;  
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.ComponentModel;  
using System.Data;  
using System.Diagnostics;  
using System.Drawing;  
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;  
using System.Windows.Forms;  
using System.Windows.Automation;  
using SuperSocket.SocketBase;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1  
{  
public partial class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form  
{  
    //Global Variables  
    public static class Globals  
    {  
        public static bool EditorWorking = false;  
        public static bool WEPrompts = true;  

        public static int EditorCheck = 1;  
        public static String FuncError = "Form_Load";  
        public static String NeedToUpload = "No";  
    }  

    //private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon notifyIcon1;  
    //private System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu contextMenu1;  
    //private System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem menuItem1;  
    //private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;  

    public Form1()  
    {  
        //InitializeComponent();  
        StartSuperWebSocket();  
        //CreateTrayIcon();  
    }  

    private void StartSuperWebSocket()  
    {  
        var appServer = new WebSocketServer();  

        //Setup the appServer  
        if (!appServer.Setup(2012)) //Setup with listening port  
        {  
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to setup!");  
            Console.ReadKey();  
            return;  
        }  

        appServer.NewMessageReceived += new SessionHandler<WebSocketSession, string>(appServer_NewMessageReceived);  

        Console.WriteLine();  

        //Try to start the appServer  
        if (!appServer.Start())  
        {  
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to start!");  
            Console.ReadKey();  
            return;  
        }  
    }  
}  
}
```

Comment: Can you please post an example of what you have tried and the exception you are having. Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ok.  I finally figured out how to post code so the editor accepts it.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct the dependencies seems to be messed up.

You need to install the following nuget packages:

> 1. SuperSocket
> 2. SuperSocket.WebSocket
> 3. SuperSocket.Engine

Also please add the following in your code:

```
using SuperSocket.WebSocket;
```

Might be a good idea to tell the maintainer of the library that his examples are not compiling.